# CSS Menu with Round Corners

Tags: css, menu

I want to create a navigation menu that has rounded corners like on the image below, and I also want it to be with CSS only and not images.

[Click Here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrXPK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `border-radius` Property.

```
 Eg : border-radius: 4px;
```

**Update**

```css
li {
   margin-left: 2px;
   padding:5px;
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 6px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About Us</li>
  <li>Admission</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi this is not fully working, it will change only left border, check my current menu at https://cainformation.com/ and if possible please provide me full css with round menu same as my question image